# How to change language version of app using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an app using Android Studio. I have finished the English version of the app and would like to enable a Chinese version. I looked up some tutorials and tried to follow, my problem is when I tried to create a new resource file but found that language/Region is not available:
[image]

What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Open your strings.xml file from Android Studio

2 - click on the Open Editor link on the top-right corner

3 - click on earth icon on the top-left corner on left of `show all keys` 
    dropdown list and select country `Chinese(zh) in china (cn)` 
    It will add one string.xml file in `values-zh-rCN` directory.

4 - Now you can see column for Chinese language to add values for your strings key.

Answer (score 1):

It's too easy just select the **Local** and click on the **`>>`** button for more details.

Hers's an example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but found that I cannot select traditional Chinese. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, for the traditional chinese language select TW:Taiwan like in my answer(edit)

Answer (score 0):

The list on the right side of that dialog is a list of your selected qualifiers.

Click the ">>" button with the your desired qualifier selected to move it to the right and see more options for that qualifier (such as an input for the country code).

Note that you probably don't want to use country code though; you probably want to use the "locale" qualifier for language.

If that dialog isn't working for you, you can of course always create the new `strings.xml` file yourself. For more details on the proper folder structure if your want to go that route, check out the official [Localization documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization).